# Is the Sage Brihaspati associated with water?

Tags: brihaspati

Check the image given below:

[image]

I am curious about a relationship, if any between Sage Brihaspati and the element of water.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the astrological scripture [Brihat Parashara Hora Shastra](http://www.astrojyoti.com/bphspage1.htm), the element that Brihaspati is associated with is ether (space or Akasha Tattva) and not water (Jala Tattva).

> 18. Deities of Planets. Fire (Agni) (?), Water (Varuna), Subrahmanya (Lord Shiva’s son, following Ganesha), Maha Vishnu, Indra, Shachi Devi
>       (the consort of Lord Indra) and Brahma (?) are the presiding deities
>       of the 7 Planets in their order.
> 19. Gender of the Planets. Mercury and Saturn are neuters. Moon and Venus are females, while Sun, Mars and Jupiter are males.
>
> **20. Primordial compounds. Jupiter, Saturn, Mars, Venus and Mercury, respectively govern the Panchabhutas, space, air, fire, water and
>   earth.**

So, as you can see, water is linked with Venus (Shukra) and not with Brihaspati (Jupiter).

Answer (score 0):

In a certain sense, since Brihaspati is considered an adytia together with Garuda and Aruna:

> Vinata's son are Garuda, the powerful Aruna and the illustrious Brihaspati are counted among the
>   adityas.

And as far as I know, Varuna is an adytia:

> From Aditi were born the twelve adityas, the rulers of
>   the worlds. I shall now mention their names to you-Dhata, Mithra, Aryamana, Shakra, Varuna, Amsha, Bhaga, Vivasvana and Pusha. In the tenth place was Savita, the eleventh was Tvashta and the twelfth was Vishnu. However, the youngest surpassed all the other adityas in
>   qualities.

But in itself, Brihaspati is not directly related to water.